# how to use UIView animateWithDuration?

Tags: objective-c

how to create left (or right) slider menu using UIView animateWithDuration in objective-c?

```
- (IBAction) menuButton :(UIButton *) sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(-self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 40, self.view.center.y);
}];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can set the frame of your view within the animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 200, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);}];
```

Comment: how to add cells or labels on this view?

Comment: Your original question implied that you wanted to know how to use animateWithDuration. If you want a full implementation for a sliding menu there are tons of good tutorials by googling. In short, you can create a UITableView off screen and use animateWithDuration to slide the table into view.